# Create a dynamic conditional validation in Cakephp

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I want to set these validation rule in CakePHP

**Rule:**

One of these fields is required but not both.

```
discount_percent
discount_amount
```

If discount_amount is input as 0 a NULL should be saved and then discount_percent is required to be > 1 but <=100.

If discount_percent is input a 0 then a NULL should be saved and then discount_amount is required to be > 0 but <= products.price for the selected product.

I have tried but not getting right way to perform this validation.

**Modal Code:**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Code extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(

        'discount_amount' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkLimit'),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid discount_amount'
        ),
        'discount_percent' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkLimit'),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid discount_percent'
        )
    );

    public function checkLimit($field) {
        $passed = true;

        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount']) && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount'])) {

            ??????

        } else {

            ??????
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Validation rules should not change any data!

So "`if 0, save null`" is not allowed in a validation rule.
You should implement that logic in a `beforeSave()` callback rather.

Regarding the validation, there is a second parameter provided containing all the `$data` you could use to validate other fields (and pull additional required data from the database - your product price probably).

Good documentation is at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Good call mentioning `beforeSave()` to manipulate your data, and validation rule to only validate

Answer (score 2):

Be careful using [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), they're not exact opposites.  `empty('0')` returns true, while `isset('0')` also return true.  I think you want to use `isset` and `!isset` instead.

```
public function checkLimit($field) {
    if ((!isset($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount']) && isset($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_percent'])) {
        //only percent is set
        if ($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_percent'] >= 1 && $this->data[$this->alias]['discount_percent'] <= 100) {
            //percent is in correct range
            return true;
        }
    } else if ((isset($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount']) && !isset($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_percent'])) {
        //only amount is set
        if ($this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount'] >= 0 && $this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount'] <= $products.price) {
            //amount is in correct range
            return true;
        }
    }
    //either neither or both fields are set, or values aren't in correct range
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `$this->data[$this->alias]['discount_amount']` gives you the correct value you're looking for, I've never used `$this->alias` before

Comment: `$products.price` is no valid php variable name

Comment: Looks good to me! 
Just need to set the product price, or get it from the db or somewhere else now...

Comment: This is slightly pseudocode, not sure what they're using for `products.price` so I just added it as a variable.  Assuming it's not a variable at that point they'll get an error and should be able to debug from there...